# как правильно поставить watchpoint в gdb

Tags: отладка, gdb

При попытке поставить watchpoint на секцию памяти, вылезает ошибка:

```
(gdb) rwatch *(0x415fc8)
Hardware read watchpoint 5: *(0x415fc8)
(gdb) info break
Num     Type            Disp Enb Address    What
5       read watchpoint keep y              *(0x415fc8)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 5.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.
```

Загуглил, нашел вот это:

> Иногда GDB не может установить аппаратную точку наблюдения из-за того,
>   что тип данных наблюдаемого выражения занимает больше места, чем
>   допускает аппаратная точка наблюдения на целевой платформе. Например,
>   некоторые системы позволяют наблюдать за областями, занимающими до 4
>   байт; на таких системах вы не можете устанавливать аппаратные точки
>   наблюдения за выражениями, которые в результате дают число с плавающей
>   точкой двойной точности (которое обычно занимает 8 байт). В качестве
>   одного из решений, можно разбить большую область на несколько меньших
>   областей, и затем наблюдать за каждой из них с помощью отдельной точки
>   наблюдения.

У меня как раз такая ситуация, система MIPS32. Но не совсем понятно, что значит:

> В качестве одного из решений, можно разбить большую область на
>   несколько меньших областей, и затем наблюдать за каждой из них с
>   помощью отдельной точки наблюдения.